# Create file with defined size

Tags: c, file, size

How to create file with defined size in C? Project needs to work both on windows and Linux, so I cannot use Create File function...

I have tried to create char array with random characters and write them to file, but I need file that have much bigger size than i can make this way.

Comment: You might like to have a look at `fseek()` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75yw9bf3.aspx) and `fwrite()` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9t88zwz.aspx).

Comment: Does it have to be a non-sparse file?

Comment: Does windows use sparse files? @Barmar

Comment: @Sparse files, alk: NTFS supports it, FAT not

Comment: The point of my question is to find out if a solution that might create a sparse file is acceptable. That's what you'll get if you use `fseek` followed by `fwrite` on Unix.

Comment: Why can't you write the char array in a loop until you get to the size you want?

Comment: Sparse File: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>

#define CHUNK 4096
#define NUMCHUNKS 1024

char chunk[CHUNK];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *f;
    int i;

    memset(chunk, 0, CHUNK);
    f = fopen("/tmp/myfile", "w");
    if (f == NULL) return 1;
    for (i = 0; i < NUMCHUNKS; ++i) {
        fwrite(chunk, CHUNK, 1, f);
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

should be easy to port this to windows. tested on linux.

Since I'm not allowed to comment (yet?): This method creates a file *without* a "hole".
This means that the space will indeed be allocated on the device. If you're only interested in creating a file with some reported size, the seek() method will be substantially faster. I don't know how it (I mean the seek() method) behaves on windows systems though.

Comment: Since the `chunk` array is global it should already be cleared, you don't need the `memset` call. You could also do `char chunk[CHUNK] = { 0 };` if you want to be on the safe side. :)

Comment: I'm a defensive programmer. But on most platforms you'll be right, I guess. Nevertheless, the performance loss because of the defensive memset() will vanish compared to the 1024 I/Os

Answer (score 1):

You can use fseek to specify the size:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/

Added an (edited) example from the link:

```
/* fseek example */
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  FILE * pFile;
  pFile = fopen ( "example.txt" , "wb" );
  fputs ( "This is an apple." , pFile );
  fseek ( pFile , 1024*1024 , SEEK_SET );
  fputs ( " sam" , pFile );
  fclose ( pFile );
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: try something like:  fopen / fseek  / fwrite / fclose

Comment: Why not add this to your answer?

Comment: Sure. There was a similar example in the link I provided, but I've added it to the answer too.